# mixin for 'container' class in Bootstrap v3

Tags: css, less, twitter-bootstrap-3, mixins

A mixin for `container` class in Bootstrap v3 could not be found but there is `container-fixed()` which is near.

Help me with ways by which i can use `container` class through mixins?

Comment: Which is near what?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11510) would help?

Comment: @davidpauljunior a mixin of `container` class that has its width adjusted by media breakpoints

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can import "grid.less" from bootstrap and simply use:

```
.your-container{
  .container();
}
```

or copy from bootstrap into your class:

```
.your-container{
  .container-fixed();

@media (min-width: @screen-sm) {
    width: @container-sm;
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-md) {
    width: @container-md;
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    width: @container-lg;
  }
}
```